# Point in time forward MySQL Dump

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have a MySQL table that stores a list of bookings that's made online. I need to have these bookings dumped to a CSV file which will then be picked up by a client server application through a SSH connection. Earlier we were dumping the entire table and so the CSV file had the transactions since beginning of time. Now we have to generate the dump several times in a day and the dump should contain only the newer records. Does my MySQL provide any options to generate a dump that contains only those records that were inserted after the last dump was taken?

Comment: Do you mean an [incremental backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html)?

Comment: Yes, incremental backup

Comment: But without having to have a base.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the time from where you need to start the backup then you can use **mysqldump** with **--where** clause like below to get the type of backup you are looking for

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password db_name table_name  --where=date_pulled > '2014-07-21 16:25:00' > backup.sql
```

You can also do like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date_pulled > '2014-07-21 16:25:00'
INTO OUTFILE 'table_name.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You can create a simple automated script for this and change the `date_pulled` dynamically.

Have a look at below links that may help you as well

[**Mysqldump in CSV format**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/mysqldump-in-csv-format)

[**How to output MySQL query results in csv format?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Comment: How do I update the date_pulled after extracting the dump?

Comment: You cab create a procedure and just pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do an incremental backup, you must start with two things

## BINARY LOGGING ENABLED / AUTO EXPIRED EVERY 14 DAYS

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=/path/to/binlogs/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days=14
```

## FULL BACKUP

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --flush-logs"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --master-data=2 --all-databases"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > FullBackup.sql
```

You could probably do a full backup once a week (like on Mondays at midnight)

## INCREMENTAL BACKUP

You must extract the binlog events

In this example, you would look for the `/path/to/binlogs`

You would then use the [**mysqlbinlog**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) program to copy everything since the last full backup.

First you execute `FLUSH LOGS;` every night at 11:59 PM

Then you go into `/path/to/binlogs` and run this on 2016-11-22 at midnight

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2016-11-21 00:00:00" --stop-datetime="2016-11-21 23:59:59" mysql-bin.[0-9]* > Incremental_20161121.sql
```

or you could simply make a backup of the binlogs folder and extract the incremental changes at yourt own convenience.